# What is the equilent plugin of spring-boot-maven-plugin for sbt?

Tags: spring-boot, sbt

Hive everyone, I try to migrate a spring boot application from maven to sbt. All work perfectly but to package the jar with sbt, I can't use anymore spring-boot-maven-plugin. Do you know what can I use for sbt?

Comment: Did you found the answer? I'm trying to create executable spring boot jar, which can be configured via maven plugin. I've sbt project instead of maven. What was your experience?